# INSERT based on a SELECT not inserting correctly with PostGreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I'm using PostGreSQL 9.3 and the latest PostGIS to store shapefiles.

I have a table, named zonages_region, that contains 76 polygons.
I added a new column in order to store the superficy of the polygons.
The geometry of the polygons is stored in the "geom" column.

I have this request :

```
INSERT INTO zonages_region(superficie)
SELECT ST_AREA(geom::geography)/1000000 FROM zonages_region
```

The SELECT is stored in the table, but it creates new rows instead of starting at the first one. 
As I have already 76 rows for my polygons, the INSERT starts to insert at the row 77.

How can I do the INSERT to start at the first row, so it will match the polygons rows already existing ?

Comment: Insert always "inserts" new values in a table. If you want to change the superficie column you should use an update instead to "update" the existing rows.

Comment: Can I still make it based on the SELECT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be an `UPDATE`. Like this:

```
UPDATE zonages_region
SET    superficie = ST_AREA(geom::geography)/1000000
```

Without `WHERE` condition, every row in the table is updated.
[Details about `UPDATE` in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html)

Comment: Seems like it worked but I'm perplex about the ST_AREA function as you removed the FROM. How could it know where the (geom) column comes from ?

Comment: @SecularKid: Columns of the updated table are visible automatically. Try the manual, it's really good.

Comment: Oh OK. I was reading the manual ^_^ and tried some stuff, but get the " more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression " error. I was still using the SELECT in the expression, tho.